# CSS: jQuery: Apply margin-right to li elements except for every 4th-child (only apply to elements that are display:block)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/PrgTQ/) (Just an example to give you the idea of problem)

I am stuck at this stupid thing and would really appreciate any help I can get. I have an un-ordered list of fixed width with multiple list items inside. These list items are dynamically populated.

Due to users actions on the page some of these elements might be set to `display:none` to hide from view. Currently I am applying `margin-right` to elements except for every 4th element using `li:not(:nth-child(4n)){}` selector. Now the issue is that when some of these elements are hidden by setting `display: none`, the `nth-child` selector still considers the elements that are hidden, as they are still in the markup. This causes the styling to mess up a bit.

Increasing the width of the ul will not work as shown in the fiddle. Is there any way I can achieve what I want without having to remove those list items from the list.

Regards

Comment: No, there is no CSS way to do it. The only way (unless you want to wait CSS 4) is through Javascript.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/PrgTQ/1/

Comment: @Douglas That could work. But I am really trying to avoid increasing the width of the list because of design constraint.

Comment: So I guess I have to iterate through all the list items and set margin for each of them individually by checking there display property in js. :( 
Do you guys think there is a cheaper way than this to do this in js/jquery?

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement to remove the right margin from the elements on the far right?

Comment: Incidentally, FlexBox will support this if you don't need to worry about the browser compatability issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it may be better to just iterate over the elements, here's an interesting approach:

```
function reMargin(){
    $("li").css("margin-right", 10);
    $("li:visible").filter(":odd:odd").css("margin-right", 0);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#set-display').on('click', function(){
        jQuery('#set-this').addClass('display-none');
        reMargin();
    });

    reMargin();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PrgTQ/2/

`:odd:odd` actually returns every 4th element.